# What bike would be right for me?

Tags: mountain-bike, advice

I live in an area with many steep hills which are all about 1000-1300 feet high. My current bike is a [Ghost Northshore](https://www.thebikelist.co.uk/ghost/northshore-2013) which is a freerider just slightly under 37 lbs. I bought this bike to ride on my own trail. However I dont do this kind of riding anymore and I am looking for a bike to cruise hills up and down and to do tours under 20 miles regularly. Climbing with my Ghost bike is certainly not the funniest thing to do. Sometimes it is just not possible. The bike is heavy, has only higher gears, the suspension takes all my energy (it is not lockable) and the saddle is very low. Its just not made for this kind of riding.

Now Im looking for a lighter bike which fits my needs a little bit better but I dont want to loose all the characteristics of my freerider. I would love to have bigger brakes and some fork travel. I found this [Cube Stereo 140 HPC Race](https://www.cube.eu/en/2020/bikes/mountainbike/fullsuspension/stereo/cube-stereo-140-hpc-race-275-bluegreynred-2020/) which has the right amount of suspension travel for me (I would like to take smaller jumps under 3 feet or so very rarely); bigger brakes; is light enough and most important: It is in my price range.

I need your advice if this bike is capable for regularly and sometimes serious climbing. The weight seems to be fine but Im especially unsure if the gears are right for my purpose. Are they low enough for serious climbing? Or is this bike meant for riding in a bike park? That is something I almost never do.

Comment: have you look at hardtail bikes ? no rear suspension will make the bike a lot lighter.

Comment: Since Im in love with the feeling of riding my freerider downhill I cant imagine to go for a hardtail bike.

Comment: Are you planning on riding trails or normal paved / asphalt roads ? I'd only consider full suspension if riding up and down mountains

Comment: I am riding up and down mountains like 90% of the time. I do have to take some asphalt roads at some point but rarely.

Answer (score 2):

There are far too many options and it's far too subjective for someone to give you a straight "get this bike" answer.

You're kind of talking about the "All Mountain" to "Enduro" range of bikes. Ie bikes that can go long distance but can also go downhill.

The all mountain type bikes typically start at 140mm-ish travel. The cube you link is one of these.

The enduro bikes typically start at 160mm travel. Cube do the 160 version of that bike too.

The difference is, less travel, better pedalling efficiency, the more travel, better downhill efficiency.

You just have to decide what is more important to you, having a nicer time going uphill and sacrifise some of the down (get an all mountain). Or just be good enough to go uphill, but the downhill is the main point (get an enduro).

For decent bike, like your cube, the difference between the 140 and the 160 will be marginal in terms of pedalling and downhill.

You just have to decide, on which side of that margin you want to be.

Comment: Good answer. With modern geometry (slack headtube and steep seat angle) there are lots of options that can climb well and also descend similar to a DH bike (at least as far as stability, hard to beat long travel DH bikes when you need that travel). I wouldn't say less travel always means better pedalling efficiency, since it ignores suspension design. There are some 160mm bikes that arguably climb as well as 130-140mm bikes.

Comment: I should probably say, I have a 160mm enduro bike, I almost went for a 140mm one, and I am glad I didn't go less travel. It climbs brilliant, and can't fault it going down. Just depends what you want.

Comment: Someone I know just upgraded from la 2019 Enduro biketo a 2020 "all mountain". The suspension went from 170f/150r to 160f/150r. The new bike climbs better due to it's geometry and suspension design and is as good or better on the downs (he races enduro so I trust his take). By the numbers it should be a more comfortable climber than my 150f/130r AM bike. Point being modern bikes are pretty amazing. You can buy a bike to take on all day epics that can also shred whistler bike park.

Answer (score -1):

So, I would have just added a comment, but ya boi (me) is only at 33 reputation, not 50, so Im giving you a nice answer instead. So just like a lot of people said, looking at a hardtail is a good choice. Hardtails are lighter and more efficient for peddling, but if there are still bug jumps and all that pizzazz, a full squish might be better. It just depends on what you value more, and sometimes you can get both. A certain company came out with a bike that is a little mix of a full squish and a hardtail. Its called the Supercaliber, and it has a 60 mm rear travel and 100 mm front travel (you can add up to 120mm) Im not saying to buy this bike (see, not a recommendation) but this XC bike does kinda sound like the thing for you. Another option, probably the best, would be going to your LBS. Tell them what you want, and they will find you the right bike (they might even let you take it out for a little to try it). However it works, good luck with your new whip!

Comment: The Supercaliber has 60mm rear travel. The shock has a 32.5mm stroke, but the leverage ratio turns that into 60mm of squish.

Comment: Voila, it is fixed.